# Proguard does not like scala object

Tags: scala, proguard

After running proguard, when i check if methods are available on the obfuscated jar in a new project depending on this last. Desired classes are there but i can't have access to companion object.

Library side

```
trait KeepOpen
trait KeepOpenObj


trait MyTrait extends KeepOpen {
  def a: Int
}
object MyTrait extends KeepOpenObj {
  def apply(arg: Int): MyTrait = new MyTrait { val a = 1 }
}
```

Depending project test.

```
import aaa.MyTrait

val arg = 1

def myTraitImpl: MyTrait = ??? // Type is well infered
def myTraitImpl2: MyTrait = MyTrait(arg) // MyTrait companion object is not detected preventing apply method usage

// But this works
def myTraitImpl3: MyTrait = (new MyTrait$)(arg) // Works
```

Here are my keep options for classes :

```
  "-keep !final class * extends aaa.KeepOpen",
  "-keep !final class * extends aaa.KeepOpen {*;}",
  "-keep class * implements aaa.KeepOpenObj",
  "-keep class * implements aaa.KeepOpenObj {*;}",
```

trait of the library inherit from KeepOpen and object including companion one extends KeepOpenObj.

Exploring the jar non obfuscate and obfuscate, they both show two file MyTrait and MyTrait$ with expecting methods but its impossible to use companion object in the obfuscated case.

Moreover non companion object like those with main seems to work without any problem.

### Update

I success to make infer companion object type and its associate methods adding following options :

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```

But unfortunately i fall on the following error when compiling.

```
val myTrait = MyTrait(arg) // error : class aaa.MyTrait is not a value
```

How can i have access to the companion object in the same way that with non obfuscate jar ?

Comment: As I recall, a reference to a companion object gets encoded as a static field in the class (IIRC, it's named something like `$MODULE$`).  If Proguard is obfuscating that, then no companion object access is possible... I see from their forums that there's a `-keep` option to say, "don't obfuscate this field name"

Comment: I see $MODULE$ in both non obfuscate and obfuscate jar then i presume it is not obfuscated.